# Perform action after SignOut() Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, firebase-authentication

How can i add a `.AddOnCompleteListener(this)` to `SignOut()` method in Xamarin.Android.

I want to navigate back to the login page after signing out. I'm using Xamarin.Firebase.Auth to login and I'm logging in like this:

```
private void InitFirebaseAuth()
    {
        app = FirebaseApp.Instance;

        auth = FirebaseAuth.GetInstance(app);

        var user = auth.CurrentUser;

        if (user != null)
        {
            StartActivity(new Intent(this, typeof(HomeActivity)));

            Finish();
        }
    }
```

Then after logging in, I want to log out and navigate to the logging page again, and I want to be sure that I have successfully logged out, but `SignOut()` has not a `.AddOnCompleteListener(this)`.

example:

```
public class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity, IOnCompleteListener
{
    #region Public Properties
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    #endregion

    FirebaseUser user;

    private DatabaseReference RealTimeDatabase;        

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.home);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.GetInstance(MainActivity.app);

        user = auth.CurrentUser;

        //Init Firebase
        RealTimeDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.Instance.GetReference("Users");

        var welcomeMessage = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.welcomeMessage);
        var LogOutBtn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.logOutBtn);

        welcomeMessage.Text = $"Welcome {user.DisplayName}!";

        LogOutBtn.Click += delegate
        {
            auth.SignOut().AddOnCompleteListener(this);              
        };
    }

    public void OnComplete(Task task)
    {
        if (task.IsSuccessful)
        {              
            StartActivity(new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity)));

            Finish();
        }
        else
        {
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.Make(activity_main, "Failed", Snackbar.LengthShort);

            snackbar.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SignOut` operation is synchronous, so the sign out is completed as soon as the method is done. That's why it doesn't have/need a completion handler. You can just put any code that needs to happen after signing out, right after the method call:

```
auth.SignOut();
// whatever needs to happen after signing out
```